# Optimizing Vega Frontier + MBP 2019 2.6 Ghz + Blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view

So I have this Vega Frontier with a Sonnet ( just for a smoother viewport with complex scenes) and I'm trying to get the best out of it in Blender. It works fine but it's not impressively fine ! I ticked "prefer Egpu" and I can see the vega activity in the Activity Monitor but the difference with the 4gb integrated gpu is quite small. 4x more Ram should make the viewport crazy smooth but it doesn't. One single high poly tree with his leaves in a new scene and it's lagging and takes 1 sec to load every frame. Does Blender use all the Vega power and if not, what can i do to make it better ?

Comment: "*4x more Ram should make the viewport crazy smooth*" Video memory doesn't necessarily affect smoothness

Comment: From what I've read, I should see a substantial difference with the other card shouldn't I? I've got 32 of ram and even if the processor is a bit light, it should be able to handle a single tree no? Or it makes no sense at all.....

Comment: More memory allows you to load more complex scenes, it won't necessarily affect your frame rate directly, unless what you were working on was already memory limited and near the hardware constraints

Comment: Not sure I get everything you said but according to you, what could I do to get a viewport that can handle more poly?